# How do I write this sum in summation notation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$\sum_{n=?}^\infty \left(\frac{x^n}{?}\right) = \frac{x^0}{1} + \frac{x^1}{x^2 -1}+\frac{x^2}{x^4 - x^2 +1}+\frac{x^3}{x^6 -x^4 + x^2 -1}+\frac{x^4}{x^8-x^6 +x^4 - x^2 +1}+\cdots$$

I am pretty sure I have the numerator of the summation, $x^n$ correct, but don't know how to write the denominator because of the alternating signs in each term. As for the starting point, $n=?$, I think its going to be either $0$ or $1$, depending on the denominator - I don't want to be kicked from this site by attempting to divide by $0$ .

Comment: It's neater to write the first term as $1/1$ or even as $x^0/1$; that fits the pattern better.

Comment: @Peter Yes, it does look better, I will write it like that.

Comment: We can get a nice short expression if we multiply numerator and denominator with $x^2+1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The denominators alternate signs, but they are of the form

$$\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k x^{2 k} = \frac{(-1)^{m+1} x^{2(m+1)}-1}{x^2+1}$$

The sum may then be written as

$$(x^2+1) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^n}{(-1)^{n+1} x^{2(n+1)}-1} = -(x^2+1) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{x^{2(n+1)}+(-1)^n}$$

I should note that convergence is achieved when $|x|<1$ when $x$ is real.

Comment: **+1** Very nice answer Ron. Much better than mine. I should have spotted the geometric series myself.

Comment: @FlybyNight: thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a condition for convergence of the OP's series? I suppose a necessary condition is that $|x| > 1$, but is that sufficient?

Comment: @FlybyNight: why would you have $|x|>1$ when the denominator series needs the opposite to converge?

Comment: $\dfrac{a^m-1}{a-1}$ has no alternating signs, you have $\dfrac{x^{2(n+1)} + (-1)^n}{x^2+1}$ in the denominators here.

Comment: @DanielFischer: good God, thanks - very amatuer mistake.

Comment: @RonGordon If the denominators converge to a finite limit then the series fails to converge by the ratio test (assuming $x \neq 0$). If $|x|>1$ then the denominators tend to infinity so the terms themselves tend to zero.

Comment: @FlybyNight: a naive application of the ratio test produces convergence for all $x$ not of absolute value of one.  But since I used a sum of a geometric series, I'd better keep to $|x|<1$.

Comment: @FlybyNight: I must be missing something.  I do not see how what you are saying is true.  When $|x| \lt 1$, the terms get smaller and smaller.  The denominator approaches $1$, while the numerator shrinks.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

The denominators in every term, except the first, are the alternating sums of even powers.

\begin{array}
.x^2-1 &\equiv& x^2 - x^0 \\
x^4-x^2+1 &\equiv& x^4 - x^2 + x^0 \\
x^6-x^4+x^2-1 &\equiv& x^6-x^4+x^2-x^0
\end{array}

Putting these in to summation notation:
\begin{array}
.x^2-x^0 &\equiv& \sum_{k=0}^1 (-1)^{k}x^{2(1-k)} \\ \\
x^4-x^2+x^0 &\equiv& \sum_{k=0}^2 (-1)^{k}x^{2(2-k)} \\ \\
x^6-x^4+x^2-x^0 &\equiv& \sum_{k=0}^3 (-1)^{k}x^{2(3-k)} \\ \\
\cdots\cdots\cdots &\equiv& \sum_{r=1}^n\sum_{k=0}^r(-1)^kx^{2(r-k)}
\end{array}

Comment: Can the two people that downvoted please explain their rational? I see absolutely no reason whatsoever. How does my answer fail to be useful?!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but at the moment of the downvotes, this answer consisted only of the first paragraph. Just that paragraph doesn't help the OP at all, hence - I think - the downvotes. They have since been removed.

Comment: @FlybyNight Ignore them. I found your answer useful.

Comment: I also found your answer useful, your downvotes were retracted btw

Comment: @Peter This is a perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: @Peter The key is to spot that it's an alternating sum of even powers. Surely that must be of some use?

Comment: @Alizter I agree; I just tried to explain why the original form of this answer was - I think - downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Once you realise that the denominators are sums of powers of $-x^2$, this becomes easy. You have
$$
  \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{\sum_{i=0}^n(-x^2)^i}.
$$
Actually that denominator is a geometric series, that can be written explicitly without summation (provided that $X=-x^2\neq1$) using
$$
  \sum_{i=0}^nX^i=\frac{1-X^{n+1}}{1-X},
$$
which gives a fraction in the denominator that can be removed by simple algebra
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{\sum_{i=0}^n(-x^2)^i}
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{\frac{1-(-x^2)^{n+1}}{1-(-x^2)}}
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n(1+x^2)}{1-(-x^2)^{n+1}}
=(1+x^2)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{1-(-x^2)^{n+1}}.
$$
After this I'm not sure whether it can be further simplified.